# How to make data appear on the rightmost edge of line graph Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I made a line graph using Chart.js but when data is added, it dosen't appear on the rightmost edge. Instead it appears in a spot near the middle. How do you make the data appear rightmost edge. It used to work when I only had one dataset.

```
myChart.data.labels.push("Average");
    myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        if (dataset.label=='Average') {
            dataset.data.push(data);
        }
    }
 );
myChart.update();
myChart.data.labels.push("Speed");
    myChart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
       if (dataset.label=='Speed') {
            dataset.data.push(stuff);
        }
    }
);
myChart.update();
```

[Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nZuX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your labels array contains more elements as there are datapoints, if you make sure they are the same length it will add it on the right side of the chart

Comment: I don't get that. Could you explain it more and explain how i could fix that

Comment: Ok nevermind i understand now thanks for the help